# how to get spell checker response json solr

Tags: jquery, json, solr

URL==>> http://localhost:8080/solr/Test/suggest?indent=true&wt=json&q=how

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2},
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "how",{
        "numFound":5,
        "startOffset":0,
        "endOffset":3,
        "suggestion":["how to tie a tie",
          "how to get away with a murderer",
          "how to boil eggs",
          "how to lose weight",
          "how to make money"]}]}}
```

I am getting above json format, how to fetch this response using jquery

Comment: Look at the [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function; it effectively performs the same request as your browser does when you access that url.

Answer (score 0):

```
I got my answer, I was looking this solution
 $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:8080/solr/Test/suggest",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function( data ) {
          var suggestions = (data.spellcheck.suggestions && 
           data.spellcheck.suggestions.length > 1) ? 
           data.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion : [];
            for (var d=0; d < suggestions.length; d++) {
               var doc = suggestions[d];
       }
```

all the suggestion value come in doc variable